# Loop will not execute properly

Tags: java, for-loop

I am writing a program for class and the loop seems to not execute correctly. It always returns the value for `i` as **0**. The rest of the code seems to work as advertised, `i` is just not increasing in index value.

```
public class Day {
    String strDay;
    private int d = 0;
    private String[] Days = {"SUNDAY", "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY"};
    String day;

    public Day() {
        return;
    }

    public Day(String strDay) {// this is my issue. I think I am going about this constructor all wrong
        for (int i = 0; i < Days.length; i++) {
            if (strDay.equalsIgnoreCase(Days[i]))
                d = i;
            return;
        }
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return d;
    }

    public void nexDay() {
        int next;
        if (d < 6) {
            next = (this.d) + 1;
            System.out.println("Next Day is :" + Days[next]);
        } else {
            next = 0;
            System.out.println("Next Day is :" + Days[next]);
        }
    }

    public void prevDay() {
        int prev = 0;

        if ((d > 0) && (d < 6)) {
            prev = (this.d) - 1;
            System.out.println("previous day is " + Days[prev]);
        } else
            System.out.println("previous day id " + Days[6]);
    }

    public int calcDay(int num) {
        int newDay;
        this.d = d + num;
        newDay = this.d % 7;
        System.out.println("calc day is" + Days[d]);
        return newDay;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("day is " + Days[d]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String day;
        Day Callmethod = new Day();
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a day of the week");
        day = console.nextLine();
        Callmethod.print();
        Callmethod.nexDay();
        Callmethod.prevDay();
        Callmethod.getDay();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, this

```
 Day Callmethod = new Day();
```

is calling your empty constructor. Not your constructor with a loop (which takes a `String`). Also, Java variables start with a lower case letter (`Callmethod` looks like a `class`). I think you were looking for something like

```
 Day day = new Day("SUNDAY");
```

Also, your `if` needs braces or the `return` will be invoked without doing anything (unless it matches on the first entry) like

```
for(int i=0;i<Days.length;i++){
    if (strDay.equalsIgnoreCase(Days[i])) {
      d = i;
      return;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try change this:

```
public Day(String strDay)/// this is my issue. I think I am going about this constructor all wrong
  {
      for(int i=0;i<Days.length;i++){

          if (strDay.equalsIgnoreCase(Days[i]))
              d = i;
          return;

      }
  }
```

for this:

```
public Day(String strDay)/// this is my issue. I think I am going about this constructor all wrong
  {
      for(int i=0;i<Days.length;i++){
          if (strDay.equalsIgnoreCase(Days[i]))
          {
              d = i;
              return;
          }

      }
  }
```

Without the curly braces your conditional block will be only the next line of code. So your loop was only running once

Answer (score 1):

```
public Day(String strDay) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Days.length; i++) {
        if (strDay == Days[i])
            d = i;
        return;
    }
}
```

If I understood it clearly this will work. If not, just explain me what the goal is on that for loop.  And place the `return` statement outisde of the next bracket.

Comment: `String` equality testing with `==` is not a good idea. Also, that `return` is not part of the `if` body.

Comment: thanks for the info.I think I found my issue after a relaxing drive. My scanner variable is day yet im trying to compare strDay to the array. How would one go about making them the same for comparison? is it possible strDay is null which could be compiling as 0 therefore making it true on the first occurrence?